# Geogebra image (PGF/Tikz) is tiny and far away from text in beamer slide

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics, geogebra

A heads up that I am using 'adjust box' package, which worked well to make the images on some other slides smaller to fit onto the slide. With these other images however, I only had the image on the slide with no text. I am now trying to put in a slide with text in bullet points and an image beneath one of them.
The issue is that no matter how I change the adjustbox parameters, the image just dominates the page and has large white spaces around it. I am trying to make this fit neatly within the bullet list. I would appreciate any suggestions!

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Simple}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\newcommand{\msc}[1]{\begin{center}MSC2000: #1.\end{center}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Idea of proof}
\begin{itemize}
    \item $\delta(G) \geq \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2r}\right)n +6dr^2$ $\implies$ have enough ($dr^2$) disjoint "bowtie" structures.
    
\definecolor{qqqqff}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{qqzzqq}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{ffxfqq}{rgb}{1,0.4980392156862745,0}
\definecolor{sqsqsq}{rgb}{0.12549019607843137,0.12549019607843137,0.12549019607843137}
\begin{adjustbox}{max totalsize={1\textwidth}{.8\textheight},center}


\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\clip(-0.3389395786418886,-5.446714475426916) rectangle (29.61267394193468,14.931419757586356);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=ffxfqq] (6,6)-- (6.990940690588799,4.032740284360088);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=ffxfqq] (6.990940690588799,4.032740284360088)-- (8,6);
\draw [line width=2pt] (8,6)-- (6,6);
\draw [line width=2pt] (6.990940690588799,4.032740284360088)-- (6,2);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=ffxfqq] (6,2)-- (8,2);
\draw [line width=2pt] (8,2)-- (6.990940690588799,4.032740284360088);
\draw [line width=2pt] (2,6)-- (2.9909406905887987,4.032740284360088);
\draw [line width=2pt] (2.9909406905887987,4.032740284360088)-- (4,6);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=qqzzqq] (4,6)-- (2,6);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=qqzzqq] (2.9909406905887987,4.032740284360088)-- (2,2);
\draw [line width=2pt] (2,2)-- (4,2);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=qqzzqq] (4,2)-- (2.9909406905887987,4.032740284360088);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=qqqqff] (10,6)-- (11.026781215719945,3.947159867620885);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=qqqqff] (11.026781215719945,3.947159867620885)-- (12,6);
\draw [line width=2pt] (12,6)-- (10,6);
\draw [line width=2pt] (11.026781215719945,3.947159867620885)-- (10,2);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=qqqqff] (10,2)-- (12,2);
\draw [line width=2pt] (12,2)-- (11.026781215719945,3.947159867620885);
\draw [line width=2pt] (17.596281060735336,6.028661229582297)-- (18.520778093585694,3.982830057148846);
\draw [line width=2pt] (18.520778093585694,3.982830057148846)-- (19.596281060735336,6.028661229582297);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=ffxfqq] (19.596281060735336,6.028661229582297)-- (17.596281060735336,6.028661229582297);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=ffxfqq] (18.520778093585694,3.982830057148846)-- (17.53895860157074,2.028661229582297);
\draw [line width=2pt] (17.53895860157074,2.028661229582297)-- (19.53895860157074,2.028661229582297);
\draw [line width=2pt,color=ffxfqq] (18.520778093585694,3.982830057148846)-- (19.53895860157074,2.028661229582297);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=sqsqsq] (6,6) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=sqsqsq] (8,6) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=sqsqsq] (6.990940690588799,4.032740284360088) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=sqsqsq] (7.514865933983603,4.427079115674452) node {$v_2$};
\draw [fill=sqsqsq] (6,2) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=sqsqsq] (8,2) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=sqsqsq] (2,6) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=sqsqsq] (4,6) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=sqsqsq] (2.9909406905887987,4.032740284360088) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=sqsqsq] (3.5309550220443024,4.369756656509858) node {$v_1$};
\draw [fill=sqsqsq] (2,2) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=sqsqsq] (4,2) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=sqsqsq] (10,6) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=sqsqsq] (12,6) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=sqsqsq] (11.026781215719945,3.947159867620885) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=sqsqsq] (11.584760534669792,4.34109542692756) node {$v_3$};
\draw [fill=sqsqsq] (10,2) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=sqsqsq] (12,2) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=sqsqsq] (17.596281060735336,6.028661229582297) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=sqsqsq] (19.596281060735336,6.028661229582297) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=sqsqsq] (18.520778093585694,3.982830057148846) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=sqsqsq] (19.36628436626346,4.398417886092155) node {$v_{dr^2}$};
\draw [fill=sqsqsq] (17.53895860157074,2.028661229582297) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=sqsqsq] (19.53895860157074,2.028661229582297) circle (2.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (13.791675212506671,4.011491286731142) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (15.024108084545448,4.040152516313439) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [fill=black] (16.141896038255037,4.040152516313439) circle (1.5pt);
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
    
    \item
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by commenting out the line

```
\clip(-0.3389395786418886,-5.446714475426916) rectangle (29.61267394193468,14.931419757586356);
```